# Check Password Against PAM Configuration

Tags: linux, passwords, pam

We're trying to write a password change application that will allow an administrator (not root) to change a small set of other user's passwords. The system is configured using PAM to set minimum acceptable password length, character classes, and so forth. Length and character class are easy to check, but PAM also imposes other checks, such as similarity to dictionary words, palindromes, recent use of the same password, and so forth.

We'd like to run our proposed password through some sort of function that submits it to the same scrutiny PAM will, ideally with a return string stating the reason for the rejection.

We've tried using cracklib's FascistCheck routine, but it does not seem to honor PAM configuration settings.